# How to create multiple operator options in one filter, and how to add "contain" filter in external content type?

Tags: 2010, filter, sql-server, external-content-type, business-data-catalog

I'm creating external content type from SQL server to business data list. I would like to create a read list operator based on search stored procedure.
I noticed in creating filter table, there's no "contain" operator in operator selection list:
[image]

Is there anyway to create a "contain" type filter?

Also, I noticed once I created the business data list with filters, there's a dropdown box for operator indicating I can add multiple operators to a filter :

[image]

but there's no multiple operator option in filter configuration page. Is there anyway to accomplish this?